# Linux keeps on losing mouse text selections

Tags: linux

This has been driving me absolutely nuts. For some reason, when I select text (to middle click to paste elsewhere), a lot of times the highlight immediately disappears when LMB is released. This also happens if I double-click a word to highlight it.

Sometimes, even though the highlight disappears, a middle-click will paste the correct selection, but other times it will not.

If I rapidly click my mouse in 2s or 3s, after 5 seconds or so, the selection will stick and all is good, until I have to select something else. As you can imagine, my productivity is seriously affected.

I've also noticed that if I come back after a while (ie leaving my station idle overnight), selection will work just fine but after a few hours it'll start acting up again.

I should also note that I'm working from a Windows laptop and I'm running Linux via VNC. I have a VNC server running on a remote Linux box and I just interacted via VNC viewer on Windows (RealVNC).

It seems like the selection buffer (or whatever it is) is getting confusing signals from other applications. I'm not really a Linux guru, obviously.

For 7 years before this, I was working from a different accounts and text selection worked absolutely flawlessly. I really have no idea if this is a problem with Linux or if I have some sort of weird setting wrong.

Comment: +1. Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is still happening to me in Ubuntu in 2020 :'(

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found an answer that worked for me on the unix stackexchange.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75534/selecting-highlighting-text-problem

In my case, xmgrace was hogging the highlight function somehow. Closing xmgrace got rid of the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Links can break. Even for StackExchange sites :-)  Can you add the detail here to improve your answer?